# Merging data.frames leads to out-of-memory error

Tags: linux, r, memory-management, data.table

I have 4GB of RAM, and am having trouble pulling 147.6MB into memory in R in Linux, according to the error message I'm getting: `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 147.6 Mb`.

How can I diagnose this?

Here is my code:

```
IDs <- read.csv('Set1.csv')  #   2 MB
Set2 <- read.csv('Set2.csv') # 240 MB 
data <- merge(IDs, Set2, by='MemberID')
rm(IDs)                      # Remove junk! 
rm(Set2)                     # Remove junk!
gc()
print('First merge complete')

Set3 <- read.csv('Set3.csv') # 25 MB
data <- merge(data, Set3, by='MemberID')
rm(Set3)                     # Remove junk!
gc()
print('Second merge complete')
```

The execution halts after the first print statement.  I can't understand where the extra memory usage is coming from.  Looking around at documentation on memory() in R, it seems to be a contiguous memory issue?  Is there a way to address this in R on Ubuntu?

Also looked at other people asking similar questions here, but the solutions proposed were Windows-specific.

**EDIT 1**

Some comments to address the comments below:

```
> print(object.size(IDs), units="Mb")
1.3 Mb
> print(object.size(Set2), units="Mb")
142.6 Mb
> print(object.size(Set3), units="Mb")
12.5 Mb
```

So, it doesn't look like the objects are changing size too much from being read in from CSV.  I'll check up on data.table() and the rest...

**EDIT 2**

I have updated my code to use data.table() and have the same error.  This makes me concerned that perhaps it is somehow particular to my machine? This just seems very strange for the size of the files involved.  `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 147.6 Mb`

```
IDs <- as.data.table(read.csv('Set1.csv'))  #   2 MB
Set2 <- as.data.table(read.csv('Set2.csv')) # 240 MB 
data <- merge(IDs, Set2, by='MemberID')
rm(IDs)                      # Remove junk! 
rm(Set2)                     # Remove junk!
gc()
print('First merge complete')

Set3 <- as.data.table(read.csv('Set3.csv')) # 25 MB
data <- merge(data, Set3, by='MemberID')
rm(Set3)                     # Remove junk!
gc()
print('Second merge complete')
```

**EDIT 3**

Checked through my data, I suspect the problem may be here.  There were some common field-names in Set3.csv, so I think it was doing nasty n x n joins or something.

Comment: You're somewhere in what is I think the 2nd circle of [The R Inferno](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf&sa=U&ei=gr-ET_f2Ms_TiAKs-fH1BA&ved=0CBAQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNFYCWUrzMj_7SOwr-EJ9Gu34VOl_w).  Merge is very memory intensive, I assume that if you look at `object.size` the csv files are significantly larger than that once you've read the into R.

Comment: I've had better luck using `data.table()` for merging large data objects, both in terms of memory management but also performance of operation.

Comment: Just a quick check, you are in a fresh R session correct?

Comment: If you don't have it already, `sudo apt-get htop` and you can watch your mem usage there (handy for everything, not just R).  I know its sorta like checking to see if its plugged in... but you don't have lots of other things open too do you?  With 4gig of ram you shouldn't be having trouble...

Comment: Yep, I was checking with top.  With more print statements, I learned that reading in is fine, but memory usage is blowing up in the merge step.  Shoots up to about 3Gb for some reason.

Comment: One of the first thing I learned when starting out using R, was never ever use merge, create a new variable instead and assign manually, takes up way way less memory. Or go wtih Chase's suggestions of using data.table's instead of data.frames

Comment: Are you on 32bit or 64bit OS? If you are on 32bit try 64bit (I guess only 3.2GB of RAM can be used with 32bit OS). How big is your swap? You could try increasing swap (for example, you can set swap to 16GB if you are with 64bit OS). Extensive usage of swap will slow down the speed of execution but probably will do the job.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am on a 32bit system, @djhurio.  Still, given the sizes of these files, it's still strange even with a 32bit limitation that I'm having RAM problems, right?

Comment: If you search for 'cannot allocate vector of size' you'll see details of what the issue actually is and it's the need for a continous amount of free space. Note that 32bits will generally limit R to 2047MB on Windows and you start running into issues like this when it hit's around 1.4GB of usage.

Comment: R needs a contiguous block of memory to allocate a vector to, so typically this will be smaller than the total amount of available memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to `data.table()` as @Chase suggested in the comments above, and deleting used objects liberally allowed me to process the first merge.  It turned out, a later merge that was causing trouble was actually doing a Cartesian join somewhere I didn't expect due to the second dataset having non-unique keys, so I had to drop that entirely.

I temporarily got around this by subsetting data, but I had a similar error later when trying to apply a model fit to a forecast.

The moral of the story is that R functions use a lot more memory than the size of the incoming vector itself, as suggested by @Justin above, measured with `object.size`. Similarly for functions running out of RAM during processing operations.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue. My problem was that I introduced NA's into the "by" column of both dataframes.

Which caused in a very big dataframe at the end. Fixing or removing the rows with NA solved the problem for.